# Tool/script for liquibase structure table generation

Tags: database, liquibase

Need to generate xml structure for tables in my database.

Table:

```
<changeSet author="u_test" id="createTable-Building">
    <createTable catalogName="structure"
            remarks="A String"
            schemaName="public"
            tableName="person"
            tablespace="A String">
        <column name="address" type="varchar(255)"/>
    </createTable>
</changeSet>
```

Does any utilities known for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create XML changesets based on an existing database, there are two ways to do it, depending on the current state of your project.

If you haven't ever used Liquibase and want to start using it, you can use the Liquibase `generateChangelog` command. A basic example can be found [in the Liquibase documentation](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/generating_changelogs.html).

If you already have a changelog and want to add to it, you need to have two databases - one that doesn't have the changes yet, and one that does. You then use the Liquibase `diffChangelog` command to compare the two and append the changesets needed to an existing changelog. There is some description of this in the documentation about [using Liquibase on an existing project](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/existing_project.html).